# Does shell script has similar type of python list

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell

Does shell script has similar type of python list,

Python script to check item found in the list:

```
  list = ["one", "two", "three", "four"]

  if "one" in list:
      print "Yes, one item found in list"
  else:
      print "No, one item not found in list"
```

In Shell script:

list="one two three four"
   How to check "one" key present in shell script

Comment: There is no straightforward `if element in array` functionality in `bash` arrays!, you need to implement it using the built-ins

Comment: Short answer: no.

Comment: Bash 4 has associative arrays which indirectly support this (like Python hashes) though.